# VBA Code: Click in Cell and Create New Sheet from template with that cell name

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time posting, so forgive me if I break any rules.

I am looking for a code that allows the user to create a new sheet by clicking on a cell in the summary sheet. The cells are dates (mm-dd-yy) and I want to the new sheet to be named that date, and to be a copy of the "template" sheet which is hidden. I have tried this, but sort of knew it wasn't robust enough:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
End Sub
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please know this is not a code writing service, so please read the following: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Provide code that you have tried and if/when you run into issues/errors post them too.

Comment: Apologies - I have tried this with no luck                                                             Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cancel = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Name = Target.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1).Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Try the above code, "Sheet2" can be renamed to "template", assuming the new sheet created is not required to be hidden. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Visible = True`, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` here refers to your "template" index and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1` at the end refers to the index of your "template" sheet as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is just part of the string. Would you happen to know the entire code?

Comment: This works great! What if the sheet already exists? Instead of getting a run-time message and creating a copy of the template, can I display a message box and then do nothing?

Comment: You could use `On Error Goto [label]` to skip that step entirely and make do without the MsgBox. 

Try this link for a better understanding of GoTo [label]: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
Sheets("template (2)").name = Target.Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.